# How can I migrate the values from a multi-value D7 taxonomy term reference field into a D9 field?

Tags: migrations

I have a node migration using the *d7_node* source plugin.

I'm trying to migrate the values of a multi-value taxonomy term reference field into a multi-value taxonomy reference field in D9. There is a separate migration to import the taxonomy terms that works great.

In my node migration, I have something like:

```
field_my_tax_field:
  plugin: migration_lookup
  migration: my_taxonomy_migration_id
  source: field_my_d7_tax_field
```

However, this throws an exception and the migration fails. When I throw a breakpoint in *Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\process\MigrationLookup::transform()* (where the exception is thrown), I can see that the value being passed is an array, but the lookup plugin wants a scalar value. The array passed is something like:

```
['target_id' => 123]
```

With this info, I can make this work by updating my migration config with something like:

```
field_my_tax_field:
  - plugin: callback
    callable: reset
    source: field_my_d7_tax_field
  - plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: my_taxonomy_migration_id
```

Using `reset()` like this feels loose. And it seems weird that this extra step is necessary, this seems like use-case #1 for the migration_lookup function.

What am I missing? How can I do this in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the *Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\process\SubProcess* (sub_process) plugin:

> Runs an array of arrays through its own process pipeline.
>
> The sub_process plugin accepts an array of associative arrays and runs each one through its own process pipeline, producing a newly keyed associative array of transformed values.

```
field_my_tax_field:
  plugin: sub_process
  source: field_my_d7_tax_field
  process:
    target_id: 
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: my_taxonomy_migration_id
      source: target_id
```